# my genymotion does not start android virtual device

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

how to fix when genymotion is unable to start the virtual device ?
bellow message is received :

> Unable to start the Genymotion virtual device.
>
> VirtualBox can't run the virtual device.
>
> Try to run the virtual device directly from VirtualBox to check for issues.
>
> Check the log files for more information. For this, refer to:
>
> https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-logs

Comment: Possible duplicate of "GenyMotion Unable to start the Genymotion virtual device"

Comment: I had the same problem with nexus 10 image. I just ignored it because it worked fine with other devices. Download other images and test on them

Answer (score 0):

maybe IP address in Virtual Box is conflict with another network 
try to make **VBOX IP Address in DHCP**

1. open your networt and sharing center"
2. click at VBOX network and open properties
3. click item "internet protocol version 4"
4. set it to "obtain an IP address automatically" (**DHCP**)

hopefully this can help you..

Answer (score 0):

After much research I found out that there is a known issue with the new NDIS6 driver, you can install it to use the old NDIS5 driver

Steps I followed:

1.Uninstall Virtualbox and try reinstalling it using command prompt.
2. Run command Prompt in administrative mode;
3.Check your Network Drivers if you are using NDIS6 or 6.+ ;
  Write >VirtualBox-5.0.11-104101-Win.exe -msiparams NETWORKTYPE=NDIS5;
4.Now Follow the install steps and finish installation steps.
5. Now try starting device with VirtualBox.
This worked for me.